# How to delete last Node of the list using next

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I try to remove last Node from the list but get following error no matter how I twist it: --- line 108, in remove_last
before.nxt = delete.nxt
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nxt'---

Here is my code:

```
@dataclass
class Node:
   value: int = None
   nxt: Any = None  


 @dataclass
 class Deque:
     head: Node = None      
     tail: Node = None      
     size: int = 0

     def remove_last(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("empty queue")
            return None
        else:
            before = self.head
            for i in range(self.size-1):
               before = before.nxt
            delete = before.nxt
            before.nxt = delete.nxt
            self.size -= 1
            return before.value
```

Why can I not apply next?

Comment: Pls fix your indentation.

Comment: Where exactly do you mean?

Comment: I assume `remove_last` is a method of the `Deque` class. As you show it, it is not. Also, you have a mix of 3/4 spaces per level.

Comment: fixed it here, indentations is correct

Answer (score 0):

I think you miscounted and forgot about the singleton case:

```
def remove_last(self):
    if self.head is None:  # empty
        print("empty queue")
        return None
    if self.head is self.tail:  # one element (there can still be no `before`)
        val = self.head.value
        self.head = self.tail = None
        self.size = 0 
        return val
    before, delete = self.head, self.head.nxt
    while delete.nxt:  # why rely on size (but it should be size-2 iterations)
       before, delete = before.nxt, delete.nxt
    before.nxt = None
    self.size -= 1
    return delete.value
```

As indicated in the comments, the general case case would require `size-2` iterations. Simplest case: 2 elements, then `before` would be `self.head`, which means `0` iterations.

Comment: I get error in  before.nxt = delete.None, SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Fixed that. Either `None` or `delete.nxt`  (which must be `None` anyway)

Comment: while delete.nxt:  # why rely on size (but it should be size-2 iterations)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nxt'

Comment: Then, you have some error in another method, because that means that `self.head.nxt` is `None` despite head and tail not being the same node.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. It was None because I was jumping to the next node after last node, which didn't exist

```
      else:
        node = self.head
        for i in range(self.size-2):
           node = node.nxt
        node.nxt = None
```